# Possible Conference Speaking Sponsorships -- 2011

Tags: discussion

We're evaluating the feasibility of **sponsoring a member of the Android community to speak at a conference in 2011**.

Speaking is a relatively big "ask", so this needs to be planned many months in advance. Let's get started!

We'd like the community to establish **where** ...

> What relevant Android conferences are coming up in 2011 that have open speaker slots or calls for papers?

... and then **who**.

> Which members of the community are strongly interested in being sponsored by Stack Exchange, Inc to speak at one of the above conferences in 2011?

To be clear, the speaker is free talk about anything he or she wants so long as it would be roughly on topic for this site -- with a quick acknowledgement of support from Stack Exchange and a mention of the community here.

Comment: Aw man, I wish I could.  Cool idea though!

Answer (score 3):

I spoke at [Andevcon](http://andevcon.com/) in March. The event was packed and lots of interested people, including more than a few names I recognize from StackOverflow. It was a bit disorganized, but for a first effort, it was good. They are having another event in November 2011 in the Bay Area.

BTW, I'm **not** campaigning to be the speaker, just pointing out the possible venue.

Answer (score 2):

I think a big issue is going to be finding relevant conferences. Google IO sold out in a ridiculously short time, plus I'm pretty sure they don't put out a call for speakers. AnDevCon was OK, but I was pretty disappointed in it as an advanced Android user/developer. Might need to look to some more general conferences such as [MADExpo](http://madexpo.us/register) which I saw advertised on MSDN.

After a conference is found, finding a speaker shouldn't be a problem: there are plenty of Android fans and developers with plenty to say.